# Is it common for a 3 month old baby to drool and suck their fingers?

Tags: infant, behavior, newborn, habits

My son has just turned 3 months old.

Recently I have observed him drooling and sucking his fingers. He usually drools more after feeding and sucks his fingers almost all the time.

Is this common or abnormal behaviour?

What might be the root cause and how can we break his habits?

Answer (score 12):

Absolutely.  What you're seeing is entirely normal in babies, particularly around 3+ months old.  Among other things, he might be beginning to teethe; both of those things are associated with teething.  Drooling is associated with basically everything for many babies, and sucking on fingers (or thumbs or other things) is also very normal.

If the drooling is truly excessive, you may want to talk to your pediatrician to ensure it's not due to a few particular causes (low muscle tone, in particular).  Otherwise, buy a lot of bibs, and put a bib on him at all times, over his shirt, or under it if over is a problem.  Make sure it's a safe bib (that cannot choke him).  Many bibs must be removed for sleeping, although I think some are safe(r).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, completely normal, and you should absolutely NOT try to "break his habits!" Drooling and chewing on anything that's handy is a natural response to impending teething. If you don't want him to chew on his fingers, you can give him something else for teething, but I think fingers are best, because teethers can get lost and cause unnecessary distress if he can't find them or get them into his mouth. You can also be confident that none of his fingers are going to break off and become a choking hazard.

Comment: Also, the cleanliness of hands is much easier to maintain than the cleanliness of teethers.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, ours baby girl has been drooling since she was 9 weeks.
Babies can begin teething long before you see a tooth.
But that doesn't mean that she is indeed teething, Sometimes babies drool for no reason. 
My tip :)
Chances are that your washing cycle has become much more frequent now you have a baby. You must use [bandana bibs](https://youtu.be/hiEmYjhVIGM).
While bibs wont prevent mess, a bib does provide a layer of protection between your baby’s meal and the clothes which they are wearing. Rather than constantly washing baby food coated clothes, you simply clean the bib instead :) it save lot of time and your baby is clean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, drooling and sucking fingers are very common habits. At the time of teething, sucking fingers helps soothe sore gums and is a baby's way of calming himself. Drooling is common but if your baby is in danger of choking or gagging or if he finds any difficulty in breathing then you should consult your doctor.

Sucking fingers is not a problem but drooling if it is excess then consult your doctor once.

Comment: Hi Dalia, and welcome to the site.  Your answer is almost identical to the two other answers we have here.  Is there any new information you have to provide - perhaps a link to a reputable source for example?  Otherwise, when you have a small amount of reputation on the site, you'll be able to express your agreement with an upvote.  Thanks, and welcome!

Answer (score 0):

I have a son of 4 month now who usually is sucking his fingers. At first I thought it was dangerous, but as time went on I just let him be, because at first he wasn't doing that. I think over time he will learn to stop himself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice article with a guide for teething. That seems to be the most logical explanation. My kids were moderate droolers, but my nephew would soak a bib in an hour, bless his heart.

Also, we did not give either of our children pacifiers, so my daughter, especially, had her hands in her mouth a lot. It worried me, but it passed once her teeth grew in.

http://www.parenting.com/article/guide-teething-symptoms

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that your baby might be tounge and lip tied it is common for alot of parents not to get this sort of thing checked. My 3 month old has been drooling since birth. I my self didn't think much of it till i realized its been going on to long ao looked it up and did some research and my little one falls into almost every category system that tounge and lip ties cause. Must look for a "CERTIFIED" Lactation Consultant" NOT just go to your local gp

Comment: can you elaborate why a certified lactation consultant is needed? I have friends who have had their babies tongue tie diagnosed by regular pediatricians.